# Reactor netty web client times-out before even making the API call

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, netty

My application is a reactive spring boot application, and I am using WebClient to make API calls to downstream services. My downstream service's p99 is 20ms. The timeout I've set to the web client is 2000ms. To my surprise, this doesn't seem enough for web client to make the request? I checked my APM only to see a lot of API calls reported as read timeouts.

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: nested exception is io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException
```

[image: See the image attached for the span reported by APM]

I have initialized the webclient using this:

```java
private WebClient getWebClient(String baseUrl, int readTimeOut, int responseTimeOut) {
        ConnectionProvider provider = ConnectionProvider.builder("fixed")
                .maxConnections(1000)
                .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(120))
                .metrics(true)
                .build();

        EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(4);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(provider)
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2000)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(responseTimeOut))
                .runOn(eventLoopGroup)
                .doOnConnected(conn ->
                        conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));

        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
                    exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logRequest());
                    exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logResponse());
                })
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build();
    }
```

One thing to note here is that the application has pretty high throughput, and every API call to this service, results in n number of API calls to the downstream. I have also checked the CPU usage in the machine and it looks normal (~10-30%)

Comment: 1) There are no proofs "web client time-outs before even making request". 2) There are no proofs you've set read timeout as 2000ms. It is method param which comes somewhere from another place

Comment: 1) I've cross-checked the server and client request logs of both the services(downstream and the service making the API calls). The API calls which are getting timed-out are mostly the cases where the downstream didn't even get the API call. It is evident from the screenshot of the trace attached as well. The first green line shows the http.request from my reactive service, but there is no span of the request received in the downstream service.
2) I've added the method using which I'm creating the webclient. There I pass the timeouts as 2000ms.